# Parse Aws IoT message in python

Tags: python, json, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I want to realize an AWS Lambda function that parse a json message received from IoT.

I receeve this json:

```
{u'Ut': 1488467722, u'Rh': 59.4, u'Id': u'test', u'Temp': 21.6}
```

How can I parse this string to store each value into a variable?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a few options here, one thing that should work quite nicely is to make this a dictionary. You can do this using the inbuilt `json` module:

```
import json

orig_json_string = "{u'Ut': 1488467722, u'Rh': 59.4, u'Id': u'test', u'Temp': 21.6}"

json_string = orig_json_string.replace("u'", "\"").replace("'", "\"")
my_dict = json.loads(json_string)

print(my_dict['Ut'])
>>>> 1488467722
```

Note that the `replace("u'", "\"")` is only there because the question specifies a string with the unicode identifier included. This is only shown when you output a string so in general you should only use the `replace("'", "\"")` call.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If I debug the code with python 2.7 I gave this error: json_string = '{u'Ut': 1488467722, u'Rh': 59.4, u'Id': u'test', u'Temp': 21.6}'
                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @Federico I've updated the answer to correct this, you either need to enclose the string in double quotes, or escape each inner single quote (u'Ut' -> u\'Ut\')

Comment: I tried before with double quotes but I get this error now: ValueError: Expecting property name: line 1 column 2 (char 1). Thanks

Comment: @Federico, it seems that the json library likes the property names in double quotes, I've updated the answer, this version works for me.

Comment: Yes, but I need to extract the json fiel from the original string: {u'Ut': 1488467722, u'Rh': 59.4, u'Id': u'test', u'Temp': 21.6}.

Comment: @Federico, I've set the string back to the original version and added some replace calls to convert it to a format the json library likes. Does this solve your problem? Please note that the "u's" will probably not need replacing in practice, as they generally only appear when you print a string, so you may not need the first replace call, just the second.

Comment: Yes! It solved my problem! Thanks Tim for your time!